# What is the best way to enable SSL/HTTPS on Azure web app

Tags: azure, ssl, https, azure-web-app-service

I'm using azure to host my blog.

But it is not secured by SSL bindings. See [blog page](http://catchts.com/)

I'd like to enable it, but I'm using D1 tier, which has not ssl binding by default
[image]

As far as I understand, I should scale up my app to B1 tier to be able to enable ssl, but extimated cost is 46EUR/month, which is far beyond my budget.

So , my question is:

**Is there another way to add SSL binding to my app ?**
**Is 46.17 EUR fixed month price ?**

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think you can find a free solution.
As a options, you can:

1. Use Azure Front Door (pay-per-request: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/frontdoor/).
2. Create linux-based proxy server, for 10-15$, and setup proxy and use it as a ssl-termination.

Comment: Thanks @Oleg Shalnov. I updated the question:Is 46.17 EUR fixed month price ?

Comment: I would agree, using Front Door might be the cheapest workaround here

Comment: @captain-yossarian yes, fixed pool price if you will use 1 scale unit (no any scale-out rules and etc.)

Comment: Azure is pretty expensive

Comment: @captain-yossarian Agree with you, Azure is pretty expensive, although they are great platform. It is suitable for large application. But for small site, shared hosting is great choice. For Europe hosting, you may check Hostforlifeasp.net, they support latest Asp.net Core, and pretty cheap.

Comment: @TheGunners thanks for comment. I'm using Vercel. It is completely free. THey even have free ssl

Comment: @captain-yossarian Nice. Thanks for sharing. It is same like Hostforlifeasp.net, they also offer free SSL.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, to create custom TLS/SSL bindings or enable client certificates for your App Service app, your App Service plan must be in the **Basic** and above tier ( Standard, Premium, or Isolated tier). It is the ASP (App Service Plan) tier.

Within an ASP, you can provision *unlimited** WebApps.
-Since you pay for the computing resources your App Service plan allocates, you can potentially save money by putting [multiple apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/app-service/overview-hosting-plans#should-i-put-an-app-in-a-new-plan-or-an-existing-plan) into one App Service plan. You can continue to add apps to an existing plan as long as the plan has enough resources to handle the load.

**You don't get charged** for using the App Service features that are available to you (configuring custom domains, TLS/SSL certificates, deployment slots, backups, etc.). The exceptions are: App Service Domains, App Service Certificate, IP-based TLS connections.

Here - B1 is the ASP and you're correct it is 46.17 EUR/month, for the plan- You can host unlimited* apps under this - see [[pricing details]](https://azure.microsoft.com/pricing/details/app-service/windows/) for more details.

When the resources are not utilized, you can scale up and down at any time. It is as simple as changing the pricing tier of the plan. You can choose a lower pricing tier at first and scale up later when you need more App Service features. You can even pause/stop the App Service plan to reduce the cost based on your business requirement.

Just sharing additional info:

You could also set URL rewrite rules to redirect traffic away from the internal domain name and directly to your custom domain name. I believe you have already done this, kindly review the URL rewrite rules, kindly check [this sample](https://www.zainrizvi.io/blog/block-default-azure-websites-domain/).

[image]

Comment: THANKS A LOT! As far as I understand it is better to have several apps under one service plan. In my case I have only one static web page and it is too expensive for me. Btw, I switched to Vercel and it is completely free hosting with free SSL bindings.

Answer (score 1):

If, as indicated in your comment, you have one static web page, you can use Azure Static Webapps which is free (for low bandwidth) and includes SSL support.

Comment: Thanks, at this time I'm using Vercel. It us free and includes free SSL.